# How to resolve issue: "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

So here's the line that is erring:

```
@For Each item In futureClasses.OrderBy(
        Function(c) c.ClassDates.OrderBy(
            Function(d) d.Value).ToList).ToList
```

The relevant parts of the class structure are:

```
Public Class [Class]
  Public Property ClassDates As List(Of ClassDate) = New List(Of ClassDate)
End Class

Public Class ClassDate
  Implements IComparable(Of ClassDate)

  Public Property Value As Date

Public Function CompareTo(other As ClassDate) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of ClassDate).CompareTo
  Return Me.Value < other.Value
End Function  

End Class
```

The idea is to construct a list of `[Class]` objects (to iterate over) that are in order by which one occurs first in the stream of time.

The error I get is:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

I've set a breakpoint on that line.  When the error occurs `futureClasses` contains 2 `[Class]` elements, each with a single `ClassDate`.

The values are:
`futureClasses(0).ClassDates(0).Value = #3/13/2014#`
`futureClasses(1).ClassDates(0).Value = #4/17/2014#`

Does anyone see why this wee or is being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
futureClasses.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ClassDates.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Value).First().Value).ToList
```

Comment: Thank you @JasonRoell.  Dunno how I missed that you can't Order By a list.